# Can't implement "Ktor-server-auth " library in my ktor project

Tags: kotlin, authentication, intellij-idea, ktor, ktor-client

I am trying to implement a ktor auth library to authenticate user .The library is
**implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-auth:$ktor_version")** but it gives me error as follows :

```
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.ktor:ktor-server-auth:1.5.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve io.ktor:ktor-server-auth:1.5.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor/io/ktor/ktor-server-auth/1.5.1/ktor-server-auth-1.5.1.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor/io/ktor/ktor-server-auth/1.5.1/ktor-server-auth-1.5.1.pom'.
               > Certificate for <kotlin.bintray.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.jfrog.io, *.int.jfrog.io, jfrog.io, *.pe.jfrog.io]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

**This is my build.gradle file**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}


apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'


group 'com.example'
version '0.0.1'
mainClassName = "io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain"

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs = main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
    test.kotlin.srcDirs = test.java.srcDirs = ['test']
    main.resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
    test.resources.srcDirs = ['testresources']
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url = uri('https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor') }
    maven { url = uri("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/ktor/eap") }
    maven {
        url = uri("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/kotlin/p/kotlin/dev")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version"
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-freemarker:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-host-common:$ktor_version"
    testImplementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-tests:$ktor_version"

    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.12.1")
    // H2 in-memory database
    implementation("com.h2database:h2:1.4.191")
    // Exposed depends on Joda-time so include it
    implementation("joda-time:joda-time:2.9.2")


    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    //session
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-sessions:$ktor_version")


    // Auth
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-auth:$ktor_version"

}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
ktor_version=1.5.1
kotlin.code.style=official
kotlin_version=1.4.21
logback_version=1.2.1

exposed_version = 0.41.1
h2_version = 2.1.214
```

what is the problem here? The official documentation link is : https://ktor.io/docs/authentication.html I followed it but failed.

Comment: I solved it by modifying the dependency

    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-auth:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-auth-jwt:$ktor_version")

Comment: Also, you can use the latest versions of Ktor and Kotlin (2.2.3 and 1.8.10, respectively) without modifying the names of the dependencies.

Comment: freemarker dependency failing  if i change ktor or kotlin version

Comment: You need to change it to `ktor-server-freemarker` to make it resolvable. In Ktor 2.0.0, some packages were renamed. For more information, you can read the documentation https://ktor.io/docs/migrating-2.html.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got the solution. I have another question for you . How can I view my database as a row-column like an android studio database inspection or MySQL admin? I am using expose and h2 databases here.

Comment: Since this question isn't related to your original problem, can you post another question?